# ASP.NET gridview row onclick

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, onclick

I'm attempting to have an onclick event added to a row once the data is bound to a gridview webcontrol. The code below is not adding any attributes (checked the viewsource once the page is created) and, of course, no functionality is added. Right now, I've just got the onclick printing to the page, but eventually it will link to another page. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Also, thanks to the stackoverflow community at large. This community has always been a great help. Plan to go through some posts myself this weekend and start answering questions as I can to give back a bit.

C# server-side

```
protected void dataTbl_RowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs e){
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("id",e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "rowClick('"+e.Row.RowIndex+"')");

        }
```

Javascript client-side

```
function rowClicked(counter){
    document.write(counter);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using this in the RowDataBound of my GridView, to add the attribute to select the row:

```
protected void grvSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        switch (e.Row.RowType)
        {
            case DataControlRowType.Header:
                //...
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#93A3B0'; this.style.color='White'; this.style.cursor='pointer'");
                if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
                {
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", String.Format("this.style.color='Black';this.style.backgroundColor='{0}';", grvSearch.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor.ToKnownColor()));
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", String.Format("this.style.color='Black';this.style.backgroundColor='{0}';", grvSearch.RowStyle.BackColor.ToKnownColor()));
                }
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(grvSearch, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
                break;
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        //...throw
    }
}
```

And this to catch de event when an user click the row:

```
protected void grvSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Do wherever you want with grvSearch.SelectedIndex                
    }
    catch
    {
        //...throw
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using an onclick event server-side. I'm linking up a javascript method with my onclick event. The first problem though, is it doesn't even add the attributes on data bind, and I believe I'm using the same method as you for that. Did you see any difference between my method and yours?

Comment: Yes, it's a server-side onclick. If you need a javascript onclick, I suggest you to verify your event (RowDataBound). Your GridView contains the event? Something like `code`grv.RowDataBound += dataTbl_RowDataBound `code`? 'Cause both methods are very similar.

Comment: ... I feel very foolish. Thank you for pointing out the obvious. Hard to call a method if the event doesn't even know to do so.

Comment: It happens. We are here to help. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

To do this in jQuery, simply get the row click event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clickCnt = 0;
    $('table tr').click(function(){
        clickCnt++;
        //Do something 
    });
});
```

With that, I recommend setting the TR **ID** to the primary key to the object that is displayed in the row.

Answer (score 3):

Is the `Grid` set up to call `dataTbl_RowDataBound` event? If you debug with a breakpoint in that event, does that event get fired?

Comment: And the foolishness of small mistakes is made. I had an issue in my event call. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use rowcommand event if it's not working.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx